# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() while uploading image

Tags: php, html, image, foreach, upload

I have some croping php code. And I hove some problem with it.

Some pictures I can upload, and some can't. I don't know why.

When I can't upload pictuer, it show error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...
```

I don't know why, need help

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "JPG", "PNG", "GIF");
$max_file_size = 1024*3000; //3 MB
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                $kaboom = explode(".",$name);
                $fileExt = end($kaboom);
                $target_file = "uploads/$name";
                $thumbnail = "uploads/thumb_$name";

                $image_info = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f]);
                $image_width = $image_info[0];
                $image_height = $image_info[1];

                $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor('1000', '800');
                $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f]);
                imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $width/2, $height/2, '1000', '800');
                imagejpeg($canvas, $path.$name.'_cropped.jpg', 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**When i put :**

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_FILES); echo '</pre>';
```

**it show :**

```
array(1) {
  'files' =>
  array(5) {
    'name' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(12) "IMG_1281.JPG"
      [1] =>
      string(12) "IMG_1282.JPG"
    }
    'type' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(0) ""
      [1] =>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    'tmp_name' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(0) ""
      [1] =>
      string(23) "D:\wamp\tmp\phpF735.tmp"
    }
    'error' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      int(1)
      [1] =>
      int(0)
    }
    'size' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      int(0)
      [1] =>
      int(453437)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_FILES); echo '</pre>';` and see if it outputs anything? If it does, edit your question to include the output.

Comment: Note that `if (isset($_POST))` is not of much use. It will always return true; a more useful check would be: `if (!empty($_POST))`.

Comment: While you're at it, please also post the HTML markup you're using the upload the file. Does it have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set properly?

Comment: @AmalMurali i update question, i put enctype, and think isset($_POST) is not fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

have you checked in your html how your file input looks?

Foreach expects values in an array, so if your form submits using enctype="multipart/form-data" and your file input looks like below, you shouldn't have problems.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
```

Let me know if this solves anything